# How to create private network in hyperledger composer tools

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to create an application on Hyperledger Fabric using Hyperledger Composer as developing environment.

But whenever I test my code through Playground, it uses the browser version.

I want to set up my own private network and I initially thought I need to work on the BYFN script and create it manually. But I'm still not sure about this. I've struggled a lot but unable to find anything on this.

I just wanted to understand the Composer network. 
I wish to build an application with peers maintaining the network:

1. www.a.com
2. www.b.com

How will I run this for the compose?
How it will get install in the composer?

Any document on this will be beneficial for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading the Hyperledger Composer documentation: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction.html

In particular you first need to create a business network, and to begin with your first network I suggest you to use Hyperledger Composer Playground with a template to understand how does it work. Follow this tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/playground-tutorial

If you don't want to use a local version of Playground you can install it on your computer following this guide: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools

When you developed your business network you cand export it as a business network card from Playground and install on a two organizations Hyperledger Fabric network following this tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org